# Show list item rows after button clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I try to develop custom list items. Only `<?php echo $row['title']; ?>` should be diplayed in the list items when the page become loaded. After the user click  `<button id="show" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Details</button>` the discription and country should become displayed. How can I realize that? I dont have any experience with something like this.

example( I use for this blockquotes):

before the button clicked the list item show this:

> I search a car

after the button is clicked the list item show this:

> I search a car
>
> The car should have a blue color and four wheels
>
> Germany

```
    <ul class="list-group">
<?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>             
                    
        
        <li class="list-group-item ">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php echo $row['country']; ?></p>
            <span class="pull-right">
        <button id="show" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Details</button>        
      </span>
        </li>
        
    
                                    
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Hide `.list-group-item-text` in CSS using `.list-group-item-text { display:none }`
2. remove `id="show"` and use a class - I use `btn-info` - this is mandatory since ID must be unique
3. show it with `.show()` or toggle with `.toggle()`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-info").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // in some browsers a button submits if no type=
    $(this).closest(".list-group-item").children(".list-group-item-text").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.list-group-item-text { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item ">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Title 1</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Description 1</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Country 1</p>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Details</button>        
      </span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item ">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Title 2</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Description 2</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Country 2</p>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Details</button>        
      </span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item ">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Title 3</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Description 3</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Country 3</p>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Details</button>        
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.list-group-item-text {
    display:none;
}
```

In your Javascript:

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li.list-group-item').find('.list-group-item-text').show(); //first fetch the parent of the button you pressed and then show the children with class .list-group-item-text
});
```

since you are going to have multiple copies of the .list-grou-item block you need to change `id="show"` to `class="show"`

Comment: 99%, I used `find()` to get the children instead of `children()` but other than that, you are right! :)